# Select all items in a pandas dataframe within certain range and 1 item outside of range

Tags: filter, pandas, dataframe

Lets say, I have a pandas dataframe like below

```
    A     B     C
0  25.0  xyz   abc
1  60.0  aaa   bbb
2  30.0  xxx   yyy
3  40.0  zzz   nnn
4  45.0  aaa   bbb
5  35.0  ccc   ddd
```

B and C dont matter for this question.
Now I have a certain range 33.0 to 43.0
And I need to filter the dataframe such that I need all rows between 33.0 and 43.0 
And also 1 element on either side.

Meaning I would like to get rows with 30.0  and 45.0 in this case.
So in this case i need rows
2, 3, 4, 5

How to I construct a filter like this. 
Lets say the intervals of data is not fixed like 30 35 etc. It can be anything.

Comment: Should 'A' be sorted first, or is the current order significant?

Comment: Lets say A is not sorted initially. But I am OK to sort it if needed.
Assuming sorting say a frame with 2000 rows is not that costly.

Answer (score 0):

Or just a slice on a sorted DataFrame after resetting the index...?

```
df.sort(['A'],inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
df[int(df[df.A == 33.0].index) - 1 :  int(df[df.A == 43.0].index) + 2]
```